# Using custom JSON serialization for Spring WebSocket @MessageMapping/@SubscribeMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson, stomp, spring-websocket

### This works fine

In my Spring-based application, I have set up a HTTP-based REST endpoint. This endpoint "speaks" JSON:

```
@Controller
public class HttpRestController implements RestController {

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{user}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public getUser(@PathVariable User user) { 
        User jsonFriendlyUser = new JacksonAnnotatedUser(user);
        return jsonFriendlyUser;
    }

}
```

As these JSON payloads have to follow unusual naming conventions, I used annotations such as `@JsonRootName` and `@JsonProperty` to customize the serialized property names:

```
@JsonRootName("uussaaar")
public class JacksonAnnotatedUser implements User {

    //...

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("naammee")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonSerialize(using = FriendsJsonSerializer.class )
    public Set<User> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getUnimportantProperty() {
        return unimportantProperty;
    }

}
```

With this custom JSON metadata, querying `/users/123` via HTTP returns the following JSON payload:

```
{"uussaaar":
    {
        "id":123,
        "naammee":"Charlie",
        "friends": [456, 789]
    }
}
```

---

### The following doesn't work as expected

Now I am playing around with Spring's WebSocket support: I want to create a **STOMP-based** REST endpoint. Therefore i created a `StompRestController` like this:

```
@Controller
public class StompRestController implements RestController {

    @Override
    @SubscribeMapping("/users/{user}")
    public getUser(@DestinationVariable User user) { // assuming this conversion works
        User jsonFriendlyUser = new JacksonAnnotatedUser(user);
        return jsonFriendlyUser;
    }
```

I would have expected for `@SubscribeMapping`/`@MessageMapping` to follow the same JSON serialization behavior as `@RequestMapping`. But this is not the case. Instead, when querying this WebSocket/STOMP endpoint, `@SubscribeMapping`/`@MessageMapping`-annotated methods will result in sending a STOMP message to clients with a payload/body corresponding to the "normal" Jackson serialization rules, e.g.

```
{
    "id":123,
    "name":"Charlie"
    "friends":[{argh recursion}, ...],
    "unimportantProperty":"This property shall not be part of JSON serialization"
}
```

Therefore:

- How can I have `@SubscribeMapping`/`@MessageMapping`-annotated methods obey custom `@JsonXXX` annotations for returned values?
- Is there another way aside `@JsonXXX`for doing such returned value serialization?

Comment: The rest endpoint(@ResponseBody) just uses the Jackson mapper to convert the returned object to json. You can do it manually in the websocket endpoint(using jackson for example) and return the converted to json string.

Comment: It seems like this is an open issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2445